# Recurrence for A000670

Tags: notation, recurrence-relations, bernoulli-numbers, oeis

[A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670) contain a formula by Martin Kochanski:

Recurrence: $2a(n)=(a+1)^n$ where superscripts are converted to subscripts after binomial expansion - reminiscent of Bernoulli numbers $B_n=(B+1)^n$.

What does it mean?

Comment: This is an example of [Umbral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that instead of $$(a+1)^n=\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^k,$$ you use
$$(a+1)_n=\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k$$

Comment: So simple. Well, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.